# PRI errors when compiling WinUI Desktop apps

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winui-3, windows-app-sdk

Below PRI errors occurred when i try to build the WinUI application and my application has library project A with custom control libraries which referred as NuGet in library projects.

Library project A -> Referred as Nuget B and Nuget C. When i try to build the app with this nuget PRI errors occurred.

Currently this can be resolved by repacking Nuget once again and resolved.

Can you please tell why these errors are occurred and how to resolve? this?

```
2>GENERATEPROJECTPRIFILE : error : PRI175: 0x80073b0f - Processing Resources failed with error: Duplicate Entry. 2>GENERATEPROJECTPRIFILE : error : PRI222: 0x80073b0f - Unspecified error occurred
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, when I update all nugets to last version, the app started building correctly.